# How do I verify apple IdToken like google IdTokens are verified

Tags: ios, email-verification, google-auth-library

Google has an [SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) that essentially allows you to verify the User IdToken. Does Apple provide something similar? Or is the verification process different. If so could someone please let me know.

Comment: Are you talking about Sign In with Apple?  On a web site or in an iOS app?  For a native app you probably want [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidprovider/3175423-getcredentialstate). For web sites there is both a [REST  api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api) and a [Javascript framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js)

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried following the instructions for REST api. But I'm still unclear about how I'd "Verify the identity token" under "Verifying a user". It simply says the app server must verify the items. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: Are you referring to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user)?  It lists what you need to check in the JWT.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. So the server will need to verify them individually on their own? I suppose we could do that. But even then I'm not sure about the first point "Verify the JWS E256 signature using the server’s public key". The others seem straightforward

Comment: As per your other question, once you have the public key you can find plenty of JWT libraries in npmjs that can help with JWT verification

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paulw11 what's most popular?

Comment: Any solution you got @Zephyr

Comment: @ShashankShah Posted the solution I ended up using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the library [verify-apple-id-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verify-apple-id-token) to help with the verification process.